# Javascript DOM: Find unattached node

Tags: javascript, dom

How can i find a node that is not attached?

A sample code:

```
var newElem = document.createElement('div');
newElem.id = 'newDiv';
newElem = null;
```

How do may i find the `div` i just created?

`document.getElementById('newDiv')` does not work because the `div` is not attached to the document.

Comment: Why would you think you could do that if you set its reference to `null`?

Comment: You can't find it unless you keep it in your own data structure and search for it with your own search facility.

Comment: That is essentially how you delete nodes. So no, you can't get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `document.getElementById('newDiv')` does not work because the div is not
>   attached to the document.

Exactly. You've already stored the reference to the element you *just* created. So why not use it instead?

Setting it to `null` and asking how to find it, is unidiomatic.

All DOM methods act on nodes that are *in* the DOM or part of the DOM. If it isn't and if you're **intentionally** setting your own reference to `null`, whatsoever may be the reason, you cannot refer back to it as there are no more references of it anywhere and hence it's garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

After you've set the `newElem` reference you had to your element to `null`, the node is garbage-collected. It doesn't exist any more, and you cannot find it.

When you are not attaching a node to a DOM part, you cannot use any DOM methods to find it in that part.

Answer (score 0):

No matter you use `newElem = null;` or not, `document.getElementById('newDiv')` will return `null` because the dom `<div id="newDiv"></div>` you created is not attached to the `document`.

You can use:

```
var newElem = document.createElement('div');
newElem.id = 'newDiv';
var existsElem = document.getElementById("any-existing-element");
existsElem.appendChild(newElem); // attach your created element to document
```

Then `document.getElementById("newDiv")` will get your new created element.

**Note**: after `existsElem.appendChild(newElem);` executed, even if you execute `newElem = null;`, `document.getElementById("newDiv")` still gets the dom `<div id="newDiv"></div>`.